# If $k$ is multiple of $3$, then $x_k$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

> Let $ \ (x_k) \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \ $ be such that $ \ x_0=0 \ $, $ \ x_1=1 \ $ and $$ \ x_k = 3x^3_{k-1}+7x^5_{k-2} \ $$ $ \ \forall k \geq 2 \ $. Prove that $ \, x_k \, $ is even, for all $k$ multiple of $3$.

---

I tried to use induction with steps of size $3$:

$x_2 = 3 \ \Rightarrow \ x_3 = 3 \cdot 3^3 + 7 = 88 \ $ is even.

Let $k$ be a multiple of $3$ such that $ \, x_k \, $ is even. Then

$x_{k+3} = 3x^3_{k+2} + 7x^5_{k+1} = 3 (3x^3_{k+1}+7x^5_{k}) + 7(3x^3_{k}+7x^5_{k-1}) = \ ...$

I am trying to arrange this recurrence formula in a way to substitute $ \, x_k \, $ for $ \, 2m \, $ and obtaining $ \ x_{k+3} = 2 \cdot ( ...... ) \ $, but failing in the process.

Comment: What if you show, simultaneously, that $x_k$ is odd for $k$ not divisible and $x_k$ is even for $k$ divisible by 3.
So you do it for the base case in each case 0,1,2 and assume the three things at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could show, by modular congruence, that $x_{3m} \equiv 0 \pmod2$. We know that $7 \equiv 3 \equiv1 \pmod2$. We also know that $x^2 \equiv x \pmod2$ in the special case of mod 2 congruence: if $x$ is even, so will be $x^2$; if $x$ is odd, so will be $x^2$. Therefore, we can generalize to $x^n \equiv x \pmod2$. (*)

Finally, all of this translates to:

$$ x_k \equiv 3(x_{k-1})^3+7(x_{k-2})^5\equiv (x_{k-1})^3 + (x_{k-2})^5 \equiv x_{k-1}+x_{k-2} \pmod2 $$

Since $x_{k-1}=3(x_{k-2})^3+7(x_{k-3})^5$, we have that

$$x_{k-1} \equiv x_{k-2}+x_{k-3} \pmod2$$

Therefore,

$$x_k \equiv 2 x_{k-2}+x_{k-3} \equiv x_{k-3} \pmod2 \textrm{ (**)}$$

Using $k=3m$, we can rewrite this as

$$ x_{3m} \equiv x_{3(m-1)} \pmod2 $$

By induction, we see that $x_{3m} \equiv x_{0} \pmod2$ (***). Since $x_0 \equiv 0 \pmod2$, we have that $x_{3m}$ must be even.

### Edit for further clarity:

#### (*):

Let $y$ be any natural number (including $0$). If $y$ is odd, then its remainder upon division by $2$ must be $1$ (by the definition of odd numbers: those which are not divisible by $2$). If $y$ is even, then its remainder upon division by $2$ must be $0$ (by the definition of even numbers: those which are divisible by $2$).

First, if $y$ is odd, we have the following congruence $\pmod2$:

$$y \equiv 1 \pmod2$$

Using the properties of modular congruence, the relation will still be valid upon multiplication of both sides by any integer. If we multiply both sides by $y$:

$$y^2 \equiv y \pmod2$$

Since $y$ is obviously still congruent to $1$, the above equiation can also be written as:

$$y^2 \equiv y \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$$

I can once again multiply all sides by $y$, obtaining:

$$y^3 \equiv y^2 \equiv y \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$$

By induction, then, we arrive at the conclusion that

$$y^n \equiv y \equiv 1 \pmod2$$

for any natural integer $n$.

Repeating the above but when $y$ is even, we would arrive at

$$y \equiv 0 \pmod2 \implies y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod2 \implies y^2 \equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod2$$

which would naturally lead us into

$$y^n \equiv y \equiv 0 \pmod2$$

So, (*) is valid for any natural $y$, as $y^n \equiv y \pmod2$ is valid when $y$ is even and when it's odd.

#### (**):

$2 \equiv 0 \pmod2$, which means $2x_{k-2} \equiv 0 \pmod2$.

#### (***):

Note that the congruence relation $x_{3m} \equiv x_{3(m-1)} \pmod2$ can be naturally extended to $x_{3m} \equiv x_{3(m-1)} \equiv x_{3(m-2)} \equiv \ldots \equiv x_{3} \equiv x_0 \pmod2$ by the use of induction. First, it has been already calculated that $x_3 \equiv x_0 \pmod2$ (given that $x_3=88$). Second, notice that $m$ is any given integer (such that $k-1=3m-1\geq2$, as the recurrence formula demands for both $x_k$ and $x_{k-1}$). Therefore, $m-1=m'$ and the modular congruence equiation could be easily re-obtained (as, again, the derivation of this congruence equation involved any given integer $m$ such that $k=3m\geq2$, not a specific $m$):

$$x_{3m'} \equiv x_{3(m'-1)} \pmod2$$

Substituting $m'=m-1$, we would have

$$x_{3(m-1)} \equiv x_{3(m-2)} \pmod2$$

Since $x_{3m'} \equiv x_{3(m'-1)} \pmod2$, the above translates to

$$x_{3m} \equiv x_{3(m-1)} \equiv x_{3(m-2)} \pmod2$$

I can repeat this induction up until $3m=3,m=1$, which means

$$x_{3m} \equiv \ldots \equiv x_3 \equiv x_0 \pmod2$$

**Note:** I can in fact impose that $x_{3m} \equiv x_0 \pmod2$ based on this induction alone. Remember, this recurrence relation requires that the term on the left (in $x_{3m} \equiv x_{3(m-1)} \pmod2$) respects $3m-1\geq2$, or $m\geq1$. It does not matter if the term on the right respects that condition or not (refer back to the derivation of the recurrence formula): what is truly important is that both $x_k$ and $x_{k-1}$ are greater than $2$. Therefore, $x_3 \equiv x_0 \pmod2$ is correct and does not depend on any previous calculation of the parity of $x_3$.

$$x_{3m} \equiv \ldots \equiv x_3 \equiv x_0 \pmod2$$

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $$x^2\equiv x \pmod 2$$

Working modulo $2$ we get $$ \ x_k = x^3_{k-1}+x^5_{k-2} =x_{k-1}+x_{k-2}\ $$

So $$\color{red}{x_{k}} = x_{k-1}+x_{k-2} = 2x_{k-2}+x_{k-3} = \color{red}{x_{k-3}}$$

Since $x_0$ is even so is $x_{3}, x_6,x_9...$.

Answer (score 1):

We are going to prove $x_{3k},x_{3k+1},x_{3k+2}$ are $even,odd,odd$ for all $k\geq 0$ by induction.

The base case can be seen by checking $x_0,x_1,x_2$.

The inductive step follows:

Notice $x_{3k} = 3x_{3(k-1)+2}^3 + 7x_{3(k-1)+1)}^5 = odd + odd$, so it's even.

Notice $x_{3k+1} = 3x_{3k}^3 + 7x_{3(k-1)+2}^5 = even + odd$, so it's odd.

Notice $x_{3k+2} = 3x_{3k+1}^3 + 7x_{3k}^5 = odd + even = odd$, so it's odd.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following statement: if $3\mid k$, then $x_k$ is even; otherwise, it is odd. I shall prove it by induction.

It is clear that the statement holds if $k=0$ or $k=1$. Suppose that $k>1$. There are $2$ possibilities:

- $3\mid k$: then $3\nmid k-1$ and $3\nmid k-2$. So, both $x_{k-1}$ and $x_{k-2}$ are odd. So, since $x_k=3x_{k-1}^{\,3}+7x_{k-1}^{\,5}$, $x_k$ is even.
- $3\nmid k$: then one of the numbers $k-1$ and $k-2$ is a multiple of $3$ and the other is no. Therefore, one of the numbers $x_{k-1}$ is odd and the other one is even. Since $x_k=3x_{k-1}^{\,3}+7x_{k-1}^{\,5}$, $x_k$ is odd then.